# The most accurate procedures to generate random number in R

Tags: r, random, numbers

Hi

I want to generate random number. I want to find an algorithm to generate most randomness numbers. But I'm not familiar to algorithm for generate random.

Please help me to find most accurate procedure to generate random number

Comment: Hello @Ali. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "most randomness"?

Comment: Your question doesn't define the goal sufficiently. Do you need pseudo-random numbers or truly random numbers? What is the ditribution you want to sample from? Have you done any research?

Comment: Hello @LenGreski. for example don't generate same random for two user use my generator of random number

Comment: Hi @Roland. I need to pseudo-random. not important  distribution of random number. I want to find to find best technique for generate random numbers that not same for any user who use from this generator.

Comment: can we have more context about your use case?  For example, you could generate a random permutation of the first 10,000 integers (`sample(10000,size=10000,replace=FALSE)`), store them in a vector, and then assign them to users as required (assuming you will have fewer than 10,000 users). That would guarantee randomness and no repeats.

Comment: suppose user use function and receive a random number. then he close program and come back again. he should receive a random number that not equal whit past number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per R help for `RNGkind()`, the default random number generator algorithm in R is [Mersenne-Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), but a variety of other methods are available.

Enter `?RNGkind` from the R console to see the 7 different types of generators currently supported by R. You can also supply your own algorithm and set it in `RNGkind()` as "user-defined". See the help for `Random.user` for details on how to configure a user defined random number generator with R.

To evaluate the accuracy of the underlying algorithms, you'll need to do some research on the specific algorithms.

Comment: please mention some specific algorithms to generate random

Comment: [List of random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators)  with links to the algorithms.

Comment: @TodorBalabanov. which of this algorithm was more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

[Package ‘random’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/random/random.pdf)

February 5, 2017
Version 0.2.6
Date 2017-02-05
Author Dirk Eddelbuettel 
Maintainer Dirk Eddelbuettel

Title True Random Numbers using RANDOM.ORG

Description The true random number service provided by the RANDOM.ORG
website created by Mads Haahr samples atmospheric noise via radio tuned to an unused broadcasting frequency together with a skew correction algorithm due to John von Neumann. More background is available in the included vignette based on an essay by Mads Haahr. In its current form, the package offers functions to retrieve random integers, randomized sequences and random strings.